# There is symbol which looks like space, but it is not a space. How to remove it?

Tags: r

I have data.frame with variable *zamestnani*. There is a list of jobs and I can not rename some of them, because there is a symbol which looks like a space, but there is not!

Concretely: First column *zamestnani*, value "Manager ", "Unskilled worker ". 
Here is the link for data https://easyupload.io/qhj7th.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `trimws`

```
df1$zamestnani <- trimws(df1$zamestnani, whitespace = "\\s+")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Appriciate it!